# forerach on associative key from sum query

Tags: php, mysql

I fetched records from a table using sum on fields
select sum(net),sum(vat),sum(so_total) from sales
like below

```
 $s=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(net),sum(vat),sum(total) from sales");
 $result=mysqli_fetch_array($s);
 foreach($result as $data)
 {
     $so_net                = $data['net'];
     $so_tax            = $data['vat'];
     $fx_rate           = $data['total'];

 }
```

> Error 
>   undefined index net
>   undefined index vat
>   undefined index total

how to get only field names insted of sum(net) sum(vat) sum(total) when we run the query in mysql.

Comment: Try `$so_net             = $data['sum(net)'];
                $so_tax             = $data['sum(vat)'];
                $fx_rate            = $data['sum(total)'];`

Comment: what do you get when

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);

Answer (score 2):

You have to create `alias`  for each fields,
Use this it may help you

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(net) as net ,sum(vat) as vat ,sum(total) as total from sales");
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
foreach($so_result as $result){
    $so_net             = $data['net'];
    $so_tax             = $data['vat'];
    $fx_rate            = $data['total'];
}
```

Comment: then you can use   $so_net             = $data['sum(net)'];

Comment: is there any way to omit sum after executing the query

Answer (score 1):

Using alias would be better idea.

```
SELECT sum(net) totalNet, sum(vat) totalVat ,sum(total) totalSum from sales
```

You will get the values as totalNet, totalVat, totalSum as key in the array

Another solution might be not to use associative array.

```
$data[0], $data[1], $data[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use foreach loop. Also use `alias` for sum

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(net) as net,sum(vat) as vat ,sum(total) as total from sales");
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    echo $result['net'];
    echo $result['vat'];
    echo $result['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use alias for sum

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(net) as net, sum(vat) as vat ,sum(total) as total from sales");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
if(count($result)>0){
    $net = $result['net'];
        $tax = $result['vat'];
        $rate = $result['total'];
}
```